# Attach Android debugger to a running process with IntelliJ 13

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea

Is there a way to attach Android debugger to a running android process with IntelliJ 13. It seems to be possible when running DDMS + eclipse (reference [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/kiKkskVV6m8)).

I can't find a way to do that with IntelliJ. If I start DDMS from within IntelliJ (Tools > Android > Monitor (DDMS included) ) :

- I can see the processes running on the device
- I cannot attach the debugger (the "green" bug icon is disabled)

I guess that DDMS is expecting to find an eclipse workspace somewhere. But is there a way to make it working with IntelliJ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the `Run` menu, there's an option `Attach debugger to Android process`.

It works correctly for me: I can attach the debugger to the process and it stops on breakpoints.

Comment: so simple... I didn't saw it. Thanks.